# AudioKit playground AudioKitUI views not showing

Tags: audiokit

Just downloaded AudioKitPlaygrounds-4.0.3 and built it. I am getting audio just fine but none of the UI views show in the playgrounds. For example Mixing Nodes, the audio plays perfectly but I don't see any AudioKitUI views in the right pane. Tried clean and build again still no ui elements. I believe I should see them. I'm sure I missed something so I would appreciate help or pointer to docs that clears this up. Using Xcode 9.1 Mac OS X 10.12.6.
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not showing the timeline view in your playgrounds.

Comment: Thanks that may be it I just hit the assistant editor and I think that enabled "Live View" and now the UI stuff appears and works.